# How to remove comma and place each value in a new row?

Tags: python-2.7

Something very basic. I have a text file such as:

```
0.34,0.35....
```

and I want to remove the comma between values and put all comma separated values into the new row and need like:

```
0.34
0.35
```

Comment: Did you consider searching for information about "python comma separated values"?  I suspect that would have proved rewarding. :-)

Comment: I was trying like: a.replace(',','\n') but getting this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: ok. I got it with:
a.read().replace(',','\n')

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it gets:

```
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

for value in input_file.readline().split(','):
    output_file.write(value + '\n')

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: `with open (...):` is the preferred way to do it in python, because files are closed on error.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also removes unneccesary whitespaces.

```
# convert 0.33, 0.34, 0.35 to 0.33\n0.34\n0.35
# assume: The input file fits into one read()

with open('input.txt', 'r') as i, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    o.write(
        '\n'.join(
            [token.strip() for token in i.read().split(',')]
        )
    )
```